# Can I create a uniform magnetic field with an n52 magnet?

Tags: audio, magnetics

I want to build a ribbon speaker and I've read that one of the greatest sources of distortion in these types of speakers is the non uniform magnetic field along the length of the magnet. I've also read that there are ways to make this field more uniform but I haven't been able to find out how.
Can anyone give me advice on this topic?

Comment: Could you cite some sources?

Comment: I read it somewhere in the bowls of the diyaudo forums, finding it again would be like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Well, it might not be true if you read it on "some forum"